# Python GUI Automation using html code

Tags: python, html, database, pyautogui

I'd like to automate filling in an online-form on any browser with predefined data from a database (probably excel or anything that works best in this case).

Since pyautogui requires the exact positon of the cursor, which may need to vary depending on resolution of the screen, I want to use the html sourcecode from the onlineform to identify the check boxes and text fields. My script should consequently be able to identify the relevant widgets and fill in the data using the html sourcecode and the data from the database.

online form: https://fms.bafa.de/BafaFrame/unternehmensberatung
(German)

data to fill in is like: name, location, zip code ...

I don't really know how to proceed, are there any resources available so I can teach myself? I would really appreciate any answer or helpful resources.

Alex

Comment: here's docs for the most popular HTML parser currently for Python - a good starting point. http://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ also FWIW, you may find it easier to read in data from CSV than excel

Comment: try [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with pandas for data processing (e.g. excel/csv read/write)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll look up beautiful soup and selenium!